# After reinstalling Arch, the windows bootloader no longer works

Tags: arch-linux, boot, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

Okay, so I'm fairly new to Arch (I installed it a few days ago) and installed it alongside Windows. It worked well, but unfortunately, the next day my arch distribution was unable to find any networks. No problem, I thought. I hadn't actually done much, so I decided to reinstall it. I formatted the partitions I had already been using and reinstalled it. Unfortunately, Windows Boot Manager disappeared from the linux boot loader. Trying to access it with f12 on start-up just causes the screen to skip and reload. I know that my windows data is still intact at least since I can mount the directory and access the data. Any advice on resetting the windows boot loader/loading windows directly with the linux boot loader? Or at least enlighten me as to how exactly I screwed this up. I'm curious. If worst comes to worst I can delete my windows partition and reinstall it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you on UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: UEFI set up gpt partitioning table then installed windows 8.1 first on a new ssd.

Comment: Google Refind, then use the install from windows section

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have reinstalled Arch unless you messed up the installation in a way that wouldn't be repairable, which is unlikely. Also, the re-installation probably messed up something in `/boot`.

Which boot loader are you using? I personally found the default [`systemd-boot`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot) boot manager included with `systemd` to be faster than [`rEFInd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/REFInd) and using `systemd-boot` prevents you from downloading an additional package. You may want to use `rEFInd` if you like an attractive graphical boot menu.

If you want to use `systemd-boot`, it's already included with `systemd` so you don't need to install it and if you want to use something else, install that. Remember to remove the boot manager that you were using before. I have used both `rEFInd` and `systemd-boot` and both of them automatically detect EFI files inside the `/boot` directory and so you should get a boot menu with the option to boot into Windows after you install one of the boot managers I mentioned. Even if they don't, read the page on Arch Wiki for the respective boot manager and create a manual entry for the OS (Windows in your case) yourself.